Firebase Authentication Jetpack Compose Facebook Login; Error "No supported providers"
I'm trying to use Firebase Authentication for my Jetpack Compose app. I've gotten Google, Microsoft, and Twitter logins working, but for Facebook, I get the error "No supported providers". I can go through the Facebook login process, but when I press the button to continue back to my application, that's when Firebase returns that error message. I basically followed the Firebase guide word for word.
Here is relevant code in my MainActivity.kt:
val signInLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        FirebaseAuthUIActivityResultContract(),
    ) { res ->
        this.onSignInResult(res)
    }

    private val customParams = mapOf("tenant" to microsoft_tenant_id)

    // Choose authentication providers
    private val providers = arrayListOf(
        AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
        AuthUI.IdpConfig.MicrosoftBuilder()
            .setCustomParameters(customParams)
            .build(),
        AuthUI.IdpConfig.TwitterBuilder().build(),
        AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build()
    )

    // Create and launch sign-in intent
    private val signInIntent = AuthUI.getInstance()
        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
        .setAvailableProviders(providers)
        .build()

and my dependencies:
implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.1"))
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
implementation("com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.1")
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.3.1")
implementation("com.facebook.android:facebook-login:latest.release")

as well as the relevant AndroidManifest.xml:
<!-- Firebase Facebook Login -->
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_application_id"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>

and strings.xml:
<string name="facebook_application_id" translatable="false">12345</string>
    <string name="facebook_login_protocol_scheme" translatable="false">fb12345</string>
    <string name="facebook_client_token">09876</string>

I've also double-checked that the App ID and App Secret in the Firebase Console are correct and that the OAuth redirect URL is in my Facebook app settings.
